# No Menu bar in Vbox after installation

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, virtualbox

I am trying to install Ubuntu in Virtual box.

My issue is that there is no menu bar after the installation. I have tried troubleshooting the issue with many potential solutions, but none of them have worked
Finally, I tried startx after logging in to tty1 but still cant get the menu and my system is going very slow after I run startx.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you enabled 3d graphics acceleration for the Virtualbox VM ?

Comment: Yes. I tried that as well no action.